# counting characters in char array

Tags: c++

i wrote following code to count occurance of characters in given char array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){

char f[]={'a','a','b','c','c','d','d','f','e','e'};
int n=sizeof(f)/sizeof(char);
char max=f[0];
for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(f[i]>max)
    {
        max=f[i];
    }
}

int m=(int)(max)+1;
int  *b=new int [m];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    b[(int)(f[i])]++;
}

for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    if(b[i]!=0)
    {
    cout<<(char)(i)<<" occurs  "<<b[i]<< "times "<<endl;   
    }      
}

return 0;
}
```

but it shows very bad result

```
 occurs  -842150451times
☺ occurs  -842150451times
☻ occurs  -842150451times
♥ occurs  -842150451times
♦ occurs  -842150451times
♣ occurs  -842150451times
♠ occurs  -842150451times
 occurs  -842150451times
 occurs  -842150451times
         occurs  -84215045

 occurs  -842150451times
♂ occurs  -842150451times
♀ occurs  -842150451times
 occurs  -842150451times
♫ occurs  -842150451times
☼ occurs  -842150451times
► occurs  -842150451times
◄ occurs  -842150451times
↕ occurs  -842150451times
‼ occurs  -842150451times
¶ occurs  -842150451times
§ occurs  -842150451times
▬ occurs  -842150451times
↨ occurs  -842150451times
↑ occurs  -842150451times
↓ occurs  -842150451times
→ occurs  -842150451times
← occurs  -842150451times
∟ occurs  -842150451times
↔ occurs  -842150451times
▲ occurs  -842150451times
▼ occurs  -842150451times
  occurs  -842150451times
! occurs  -842150451times
" occurs  -842150451times
# occurs  -842150451times
$ occurs  -842150451times
% occurs  -842150451times
& occurs  -842150451times
' occurs  -842150451times
( occurs  -842150451times
) occurs  -842150451times
* occurs  -842150451times
+ occurs  -842150451times
, occurs  -842150451times
- occurs  -842150451times
. occurs  -842150451times
/ occurs  -842150451times
0 occurs  -842150451times
1 occurs  -842150451times
2 occurs  -842150451times
3 occurs  -842150451times
4 occurs  -842150451times
5 occurs  -842150451times
6 occurs  -842150451times
7 occurs  -842150451times
8 occurs  -842150451times
9 occurs  -842150451times
: occurs  -842150451times
; occurs  -842150451times
< occurs  -842150451times
= occurs  -842150451times
> occurs  -842150451times
? occurs  -842150451times
@ occurs  -842150451times
A occurs  -842150451times
B occurs  -842150451times
C occurs  -842150451times
D occurs  -842150451times
E occurs  -842150451times
F occurs  -842150451times
G occurs  -842150451times
H occurs  -842150451times
I occurs  -842150451times
J occurs  -842150451times
K occurs  -842150451times
L occurs  -842150451times
M occurs  -842150451times
N occurs  -842150451times
O occurs  -842150451times
P occurs  -842150451times
Q occurs  -842150451times
R occurs  -842150451times
S occurs  -842150451times
T occurs  -842150451times
U occurs  -842150451times
V occurs  -842150451times
W occurs  -842150451times
X occurs  -842150451times
Y occurs  -842150451times
Z occurs  -842150451times
[ occurs  -842150451times
\ occurs  -842150451times
] occurs  -842150451times
^ occurs  -842150451times
_ occurs  -842150451times
` occurs  -842150451times
a occurs  -842150449times
b occurs  -842150450times
c occurs  -842150449times
d occurs  -842150449times
e occurs  -842150449times
f occurs  -842150450times
```

please help me what is wrong?

Comment: Your first task is to indent your code properly in order to make it legible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initalize the "malloc"ed (`new`) area to 0, it contains garbage.

Comment: This is not the problem, the array named "b" is initialized properly. The actual problem is the wrong indexing in that array.

Comment: @Yexo: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the original code. Your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said the mistake you did, I will give you another way of doing. Since there are 256 ASCII characters, just allocated a character array of that size.

```
char mapCount[256];
std::fill(mapCount, mapCount+256, 0); // std::fill is from <algorithm> header
```

Now as you did earlier, just traverse through the input sequence and the increase the corresponding mapCount value. i.e.,

```
++mapCount[(int)inputSequence[i]];
```

Finally output `mapCount` indexes whose value is greater than 0. Converting the index to char will give you the actual character. As @Kerrek SB suggested, there is a notion of key association with a value. You can use the associative container std::map for this task though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your b array is not initialized ...

my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Allocated buffer should be initialized to zero

`int *b=new int [m];

memset(b, 0, sizeof(int) * m);`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I want to dig through this code, but since you tagged this as C++, I recommend The C++ Way of doing this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

std::map<char, unsigned int> histogram;

// Counting
for (char * it = f; it != f + sizeof(f); ++it)
  ++histogram[*it];

// Reporting
for (std::map<char, unsigned int>::const_iterator it = histogram.begin(); it != histogram.end(); ++it)
  std::cout << "Character '" << it->first << "' appears " << it->second << " times.\n";
```

There's no manual memory allocation, no forgetting to clean up, and it's fairly self-descriptive. (If the array `f` comes as a pointer without size information, you have to pass the size information separately and use that in place of `sizeof(f)`.)

Comment: i have done it using map  it is just  training,thanks @Kerrek SB and also i forgot to delete  my array it was good  indication

Comment: OK, sure, no worries. I'm not sure that sort of "training" is beneficial for writing good C++, but if you're developing familiarity with pointers and memory allocation, that's never a bad thing.

Comment: there is additional moment i have exam  and trying to use every kind of method  to solve problems so at last thanks very much for help

Answer (score 1):

The actual "error" is that you are not initialising the memory you have allocated to zero, and new[] won't do that for you.

Aside from using new[] you are not actually writing any C++ at all, it is all C. Why not use vector? That will also initialise the values to 0 for you.

// at the top

```
#include <vector>
```

then

```
std::vector<int> b[m];
```

Finally use meaningful names for identifiers rather than single letters.

Comment: i will consider it for future

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few problems here:

What are you trying to do here?

```
char f[]={'a','a','b','c','c','d','d','f','e','e'};
int n=sizeof(f)/sizeof(char);
char max=f[0];
for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(f[i]>max)
    {
       max=f[i];
    }
}
```

This code when finished will have assigned `max` the value of the highest character in the array, in this case `e`.

And here?

```
int m=(int)(max)+1;
//cout<<m;
int  *b=new int [m];
```

This code will allocate a new array of integers, of size `m`, which will be `'e' + 1`.  Almost certainly not what you want.  You want this to be the length of your string (`n`).

As others have already stated, `b` will contain uninitialized values which will also cause some unwanted behavior.

Comment: no   i can't agree @chad (int)(max)+1 is first convert maximum character  to int and than plus 1  it is like this  consider array  int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6}  i need maximum 6 because we want to access element 6 int this case we should create array  with seven number   which is numbered from 0 to 6 and will not be any problem or index  out problem  when try to access 6

Comment: But max is a character `e`.  Converting this to `int` with a `C-style` cast like you are doing is assigning `m` the value `101`.  So the statement `int* b = new int[m]` is declaring an array of `102` integers.