# C++ count chars in a string

Tags: c++, string, character

I need to count the number of an input character there is in an input sentence. I am so close however I keep getting this error:

```
countchar.cpp:19:19: error: empty character constant
countchar.cpp: In function â:
countchar.cpp:26:75: error: could not convert â from â to â



#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void WordOccurenceCount(string, int);
int main()
{
    char character;
    string sentence;
    char answer;
    string cCount;
    while(1) {

                cout << "Enter a char to find out how many times it is in a sentence: ";                       
        cin >> character;
        cout << "Enter a sentence and to search for a specified character: ";
        cin >> sentence;
        if(character == '' || sentence == "" )
    {
            cout << "Please enter a valid answer:\n";
            break;

    }
    else {
        cCount = WordOccurenceCount(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), character);
        cout << "Your sentence had" << cCount << character 
             << "character(s)"; 
     }

cout << "Do you wish to enter another sentence (y/n)?: ";
cin >> answer;
if (answer == 'n'){
    break;
    }
}
return 0;
}

int WordOccurrenceCount( string const & str, string const & word )
{
   int count;
   string::size_type word_pos( 0 );
   while ( word_pos!=string::npos )
   {
           word_pos = str.find(word, word_pos );
           if ( word_pos != string::npos )
           {
                   ++count;

     // start next search after this word 
                   word_pos += word.length();
           }
   }

   return count;
```

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Your title and question says "count chars", but your code looks like it is counting *words*?

Comment: You mean the number of "strings" in  some text ? or the number of characters in a string ??

Comment: @ArneMertz the thread you posted is related to java not C++

Comment: @stellarossa just noticed, thanks. So here are others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363257/counting-characters-in-char-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870263/c-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string-using-findstr-index

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an empty character.

Just write

```
if (sentence == "")
{
        cout << "Please enter a valid answer:\n";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After counting (please mark erroneous lines somehow in the future) one of the problems was this line:

```
if(character == '' || sentence == "" )
```

In C++ (and C) you can't have empty character literals.

When you read the `character` and nothing is entered you get the newline, so the first check should be `character == '\n'`.

As for the string, there is a very simple method of checking if a string is empty: [`std::string::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty):

```
sentence.empty()
```

So the complete condition should be

```
if (character == '\n' || sentence.empty()) { ... }
```

---

As for the other errors, there are really *multiple* errors: To start with you declare `WordOccurenceCount` to take two arguments, a string and an integer. You then call it with three arguments, none of which are of the correct type.

Then in the definition of `WordOccurenceCount` you have different arguments compared to the declaration.

---

Finally, if you want to count the number of time a certain character is in a string, then you might want to look at the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) available in C++, especially [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
std::string sentence;
std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);

char character;
std::cout << "Enter a character to be found: ";
std::cin >> character;

long count = std::count(std::begin(sentence), std::end(sentence), character);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with this code:
 1. C++ does not take empty chars : `if(character == '')`
 2. The arguments from your function `WordOccurrenceCount` do not match your declaration.
 3. `sentence.begin()` is of String_iterator type, cannot be converted to string. (As expected by your `WordOccurrenceCount` function)
 4. Again, `sentence.end` is also of String_iterator type, cannot be converted to int (As expected by your function declaration) or string (as expected by your function definition).

Comment: When you take char as input, the user never enters nothing (which I believe is the reason for this if statement). Even if the user enters nothing and presses enter, he still **presses enter** which is a character. Try checking if the char given by user is '\n'.