# C++ count number of characters in a string

Tags: c++, string

I am so close, I need to count the number of given characters in a given string. It needs to loop over and over again but i keep getting this error:

```
countchar.cpp:27:22: error: â was not declared in this scope
countchar.cpp:27:38: error: â was not declared in this scope
countchar.cpp:27:61: error: â cannot be used as a function
```

I really am not too familiar with the algorith of count but if someone could help out, that would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char character;
string sentence;
char answer;
while(1) {

    cout << "Enter a character to count the number of times it is in a              sentence: ";
    cin >> character;
    cout << "Enter a sentence and to search for a specified character: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);
    if(character == '\n' || sentence.empty())
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid answer:\n";
        break;

    }


    else {
        int count = count(begin(sentence), end(sentence), character);
        cout << "Your sentence had" << count << character 
             << "character(s)"; 
     }

cout << "Do you wish to enter another sentence (y/n)?: ";
cin >> answer;
if (answer == 'n'){
    break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ count chars in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929758/c-count-chars-in-a-string)

Comment: I assume it is a copy / paste error but there is a missing quote and semicolon on the first cout.

Answer (score 7):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
int count = count(begin(sentence), end(sentence), character);
```

You declare a variable `count` and immediately after you use it as a function. You have to rename the variable (to, say, `c`) to use function `std::count`.

As for the remaining errors, you should use `sentence.begin()` instead of `begin(sentence)` and similarly `sentence.end()` instead of `end(sentence)`.

Comment: thanks also says i didnt declare 2 things in that same line, does that mean begin and end? if so how do i declare?

Comment: @user2939276 you need the `<iterator>` header for `std::begin` and `std::end`. You should get rid of `using namespace std;` to avoid confusion. You also need C++11 support for that. Otherwise use `sentence.begin()` and `sentence.end()` as suggested here.